# Adding self-edge in a graphical plot with Python's `daft` library

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, daft

I want to add an edge that link beta to beta, in the following plot:

[image]

Is generated the following code using [DAFT](http://daft-pgm.org/):

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc("font", family="serif", size=12)
rc("text", usetex=True)
import daft

pgm = daft.PGM([2.3, 3.05], origin=[0.3, 0.3], observed_style="inner")

# Hierarchical parameters.
pgm.add_node(daft.Node("beta", r"$\beta$", 1.5, 2))

# Latent variable.
pgm.add_node(daft.Node("w", r"$w_n$", 1, 1))

# Data.
pgm.add_node(daft.Node("x", r"$x_n$", 2, 1, observed=True))

# Add in the edges.
pgm.add_edge("beta", "beta")  # Attempting to create a self-edge, but no effect!
pgm.add_edge("w", "x")
pgm.add_edge("w", "w")
pgm.add_edge("w", "beta")
pgm.add_edge("beta", "x")

# Render and save.
pgm.render()
pgm.figure.savefig("nogray.pdf")
```

But why it doesn't work? Especially with this line `pgm.add_edge("beta", "beta")`.
I welcome other suggestions other than Daft, as long as it is under Python.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I updated the code with missing 'matplotlib' header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/dfm/daft/blob/master/daft.py) from line 301 (the `Edge` class) you will see that all lines are given by straight lines based on the coordinates `([x, x + dx], [y, y + dy])` as shown below in the code for an undirected edge:

```
x, y, dx, dy = self._get_coords(ctx)

# Plot the line.
line = ax.plot([x, x + dx], [y, y + dy], **p)
return line
```

As such there doesn't appear to be a way of defining a self-edge (as such an edge would need to be curved in order to curve back to the same node).

As far as an alternative library you may want to look at `networkx`, the following docs show the use with [`self loops`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/classes.digraph.html). Alternatively you could raise an issue on the `DAFT` Github.